# Nautilus freezes when unmounting Android Device

Tags: usb, mount, nautilus, android

Pretty new at Linux(very happy with it), still at learning mode

When plug in my device it mounts successfully opens Window with my files on the phone and I am even able to copy from PC to it or delete/modify.
I have recognized a complete freeze of Nautilus when I safely unmounted my Android Device from launcher. Partial reboot can only solve the freeze.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Has anyone experienced that issue before?

Comment: Hasn't happened to me yet (fingers crossed). Can you edit your question to include output of command 'uname -a' and tell us your Android version number and manufacturer make & model?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, basically you have directed me to the solution. The issue was with my genericx(I dont really know how you call it in linux language, please correct me) so basically I just accepted an update via Synaptics and got updated this one: linux 4.4.0-45-generic and it has solved the issue fully. The android version was Lollypop 5.0.1 btw.